# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'

Tags: pytorch

I want to import the torch,but then the interpreter return this result,i have no idea how to deal with it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programing/tool/Python/learn_ml_the_hard_way/ML/scipy1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  torch
  File "D:\Programing\python\Anaconda3.5\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'
```

Comment: See possible reason here (Google search): https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/574
Do you have a directory named "torch" in your code base folder?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i found that my code wasn't run under the directory named "torch"

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/574#issuecomment-274914572  check that in your library path, have right library files with your python.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and followed the instructions in this **[link](https://github.com/nmilosev/pytorch-arm-builds/commit/8c811255de7d7e52268b204c7746bfb2be2e6893#diff-a39b761a102da294c8a6a0d8411efd20f0bde7dc8b568d38580d3899ca54498b)**

You can also find the torch path with this command if needed:

```
sudo find / -iname torch
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed the dependency using `pip install` and it didn't work. I reinstalled `torch` using `conda install` instead and it seemed to work!

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was issue with python version, created python 3.7 environment and re-installed it. worked just fine

Answer (score -1):

Initially I was running in a Conda environment got this error. Just deactivated the environment now it works.

Comment: Doesnt solve anything