# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C' even from the parent folder

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, torch, huggingface-transformers

I have a python script which imports torch and transformers but gives `No module named 'torch._C'`. I'm on a AWS EC2 instance and using Python3.3.9, with `torch==1.9.1` and `transformers==4.11.3`.

Here is my python script:

```
import torch
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, BertJapaneseTokenizer, BertTokenizer
```

And here is the error message. As you can see, it successfully import `torch`. But the 2nd line, where I import a bunch of packages from transformers, I get the error `No module named 'torch._C'`.

After reading [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/574) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441939/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-torch-c), I tried running the script from a parent folder as well, i.e., `python political-tweet-scraper/test.py`. But it yields the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/test.py", line 2, in
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, BertJapaneseTokenizer, BertTokenizer
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 2045, in getattr
module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 2054, in _get_module
return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/init.py", line 25, in
from ..models.auto.configuration_auto import AutoConfig
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/init.py", line 19, in
from . import (
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlm/init.py", line 22, in
from .configuration_layoutlm import LAYOUTLM_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP, LayoutLMConfig
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/layoutlm/configuration_layoutlm.py", line 22, in
from ...onnx import OnnxConfig, PatchingSpec
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/onnx/init.py", line 17, in
from .convert import export, validate_model_outputs
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/onnx/convert.py", line 23, in
from .. import PreTrainedModel, PreTrainedTokenizer, TensorType, TFPreTrainedModel, is_torch_available
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 2045, in getattr
module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 2054, in _get_module
return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/init.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 27, in
from torch import Tensor, device, nn
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/init.py", line 1, in
from .modules import * # noqa: F403
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/init.py", line 1, in
from .module import Module
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 7, in
from ..parameter import Parameter
File "/home/ec2-user/political-tweet-scraper/env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parameter.py", line 2, in
from torch._C import _disabled_torch_function_impl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'
```

People say that it's because I have a folder called torch in the same directory which is being picked up. But I cannot locate files named like `_C.cpython-` that I can rename. So I don't know how to fix this problem...

```
(env-tweet-scraper)$ ls env-tweet-scraper/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/ -l
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 246 Dec 28 01:34 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 25 Dec 28 01:34 linalg
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 111 Dec 28 01:34 multiprocessing
drwxrwxr-x 11 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 28 02:43 nn
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 327 Dec 28 01:34 onnx
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 28 01:34 optim
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 28 01:34 package
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 44 Dec 28 01:34 profiler
drwxrwxr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 28 01:34 quantization
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 19 Dec 28 01:34 share
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 25 Dec 28 01:34 sparse
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 25 Dec 28 01:34 special
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 110 Dec 28 01:34 testing
drwxrwxr-x 10 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Dec 28 01:34 utils
```

I would appreciate for any help! Thanks