# ModuleNotFoundError When Importing open_clip

Tags: python, clip, modulenotfounderror

error importing open_clip,
When importing open_clip I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\noahs\Desktop\New folder\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import open_clip
  File "C:\Users\noahs\Desktop\New folder\folder\lib\site-packages\open_clip\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .loss import ClipLoss
  File "C:\Users\noahs\Desktop\New folder\folder\lib\site-packages\open_clip\loss.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch.distributed.nn
  File "C:\Users\noahs\Desktop\New folder\folder\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\nn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api.remote_module import RemoteModule
  File "C:\Users\noahs\Desktop\New folder\folder\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\nn\api\remote_module.py", line 25, in <module>
    from torch.distributed.rpc.internal import _internal_rpc_pickler
  File "C:\Users\noahs\Desktop\New folder\folder\lib\site-packages\torch\distributed\rpc\internal.py", line 12, in <module>
    from torch._C._distributed_rpc import _get_current_rpc_agent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C._distributed_rpc'; 'torch._C' is not a package
```

heres the code im running:

```
import open_clip

model, _, preprocess = open_clip.create_model_and_transforms('ViT-B-32-quickgelu', pretrained='laion400m_e32')
```

Not sure how to handle this. Ive installed torch multiple times on different versions and dont know why I cant use the library.

Comment: What happens when you run `pip3 install open_clip_torch`?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having exactly the same problem. Looking at the error message I think it's more related to Torch than to OpenClip, as opposed to what other suggested. Please let me know if you found anything!

Answer (score 6):

[OpenClip](https://github.com/mlfoundations/open_clip) is a separate module. You must install it separately.

```
pip install open_clip_torch
```

After that things should work as one expects.

Comment: should have clarified. open_clip is installed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run the `setup.py` file:

This is the order of installation:

1. Install with `pip`

```
pip3 install open_clip_torch
```

2. Find folder of package (python script)

```
# Import and print the file. The output will be the file's location
# Go to the modules main folder
import open_clip
print(open_clip.__file__)
```

Navigate to the module's folder

3. Find `setup.py`. And run.

```
python3 setup.py install
```

> [Docs](https://github.com/mlfoundations/open_clip#other-dependencies)

---

Edit

See [this link](https://github.com/nmilosev/pytorch-arm-builds/commit/8c811255de7d7e52268b204c7746bfb2be2e6893#diff-a39b761a102da294c8a6a0d8411efd20f0bde7dc8b568d38580d3899ca54498b)

> From [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441939/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-torch-c)

Comment: That was the original installation method I used, error still occurs.

Comment: @Frikallo Does the edit help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out it was due to torch and open_clip_torch version mismatch. I had torch 1.12 and open_clip_torch 2.23. I downgraded open_clip_torch to 2.18 and it worked!