# why I am getting this error while importing torch.nn?

Tags: python, torch

I am training a NN model using torch in a virtual env
I tried import torch.nn as nn
and I received this error

```
>>> import torch.nn as nn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mustapha\Envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .modules import *  # noqa: F403
  File "C:\Users\Mustapha\Envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .module import Module
  File "C:\Users\Mustapha\Envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 7, in 
<module>
    from ..parameter import Parameter
  File "C:\Users\Mustapha\Envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\parameter.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torch._C import _disabled_torch_function_impl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'
```

I am using windows 10 and python 3.10.6 64-bit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate from [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441939/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-torch-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.\_C'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441939/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-torch-c)

Answer (score -1):

check whether changing your working directory would work:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/574#issuecomment-278879701